# Yii2 bundle tables in a view

Tags: php, yii2, frameworks

I am newbie in Yii2 and no I trying to show data in view. I've done it before like this(using GridView):

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        [
                'attribute' => 'car_id',
                'value' => 'car.state_num'
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'driver_id',
            'value' => 'driver.name'
        ],
        'status',
        'first_date',
         'second_date',
        // 'status',
        // 'foto:ntext',
        // 'description:ntext',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]);
```

(it's view shows 'contract' table which has connect with 'Driver' and 'Car' tables)

But now I wonna do it via common bootstrap tables, like this:

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Car</th>
            <th scope="col">Start</th>
            <th scope="col">Finish</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($dataProvider->getModels() as $item):?>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Order ID <?= $item->id ?> </th>
            <td><?= $item->car_id ?></td>
            <td><?= $item->first_date ?></td>
            <td><?= $item->second_date ?></td>
            <td><?= $item->status ?></td>
        </tr>
        <? endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

It's works too, but Car's column shows car_id..
The question: How could I take a car.state_num for showing it in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$item->car->state_num` :

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Car</th>
        <th scope="col">Start</th>
        <th scope="col">Finish</th>
        <th scope="col">Status</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($dataProvider->getModels() as $item):?>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Order ID <?= $item->id ?> </th>
        <td><?= (!empty($item->car_id)) ? $item->car->state_num : null ?></td>
        <td><?= $item->first_date ?></td>
        <td><?= $item->second_date ?></td>
        <td><?= $item->status ?></td>
    </tr>
    <? endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: great! Thank you so much. Now I know the dataProvider is so good thing